# wxWidgets right to left Direction

Tags: wxwidgets, direction

I have a wxWidgets form and I have a wxTextCtrl on it, it has left-to-right direction by default. I want to change it to right-to-left Direction.
how can I do this on C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the layout direction of any window, like this:

```
wxWindow::SetLayoutDirection    (   wxLayoutDirection   dir )
```

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a7d494549f7fcfed44af95f8ee364c1f9

dir may be either wxLayout_Default, wxLayout_LeftToRight or wxLayout_RightToLeft.